# Async parallel functions

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous

I wanna run bunch of `mysql` queries in a row. But its needed to wait until last query is performed and im using `async` for it. So im trying to fill my array with functions i need and then run those functions in `async.parallel` body.

Is it even possible to do something like that?

```
function getAllInstructions(req,res){
    let mysqlQuery = `SELECT instruction.id,instruction.title,instruction.description
                      FROM users_instrusctions join instruction on users_instrusctions.instruction_id = instruction.id
                                               join user on users_instrusctions.user_id = user.id
                      WHERE user.id = '` + req.params.id + "';";
    connection.query(mysqlQuery, function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (!err) {
        var instructions = new Array();

        for (var i=0; i<rows.length;i++) {
             var instruction = new Instruction();
             instruction.id = rows[i].id;
             instruction.title = rows[i].title;
             instruction.description = rows[i].description;
             instructions.push(instruction);
        }

        functionsToDo = [];
        for (var i=0;i<instructions.length;i++) {
            functionsToDo.push(getStepsForInstruction(instructions[i].id));
        }
        //here i need to execute queries
        async.parallel(functionsToDo, function (err, result) {
            res.json(instructions); 
        });
    }
    else {
        console.log('Error while performing Query.');
    } 
});}
```

Comment: You aren't clear. You want them to run in parallel, or in sequence?

Comment: in sequence, sorry